# Set first child element to li with active state

Tags: jquery

I need to set the `first-child` parameter "always" to the `<li>` with the active class into a `<ul> <li>` structure.

Any help?

Comment: `first-child` is the first child. What are you trying to do?

Comment: when u click one, and it get the active class, re-order the list so it will be on top meaning active = first-child

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code snippet will add the `active` class to the clicked list item, reorder the list so it becomes the first child of its parent, and remove the `active` class from its siblings:

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass("active")
         .prependTo($this.parent())
         .siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Hi Frederick, this is exactly what I want to achieve, however I'm trying this way <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $("ul.list").on("click", "li", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass("active")
         .prependTo($this.parent())
         .siblings().removeClass("active");
});
});
</script> and I get not results, any guessing?

Comment: It works fine for me in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BycFP/), but `on()`is a recent addition to jQuery (1.7). If you're using an earlier version of the library, you have to use [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead.

Comment: Do you mean the original source code of the page? That's only possible if your page is dynamic, in that case you can instruct the server to alter the order of the list items it renders on the next load.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
$("ul li:eq(1)").addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get a reference to the first `li` in the `ul`?

```
var li = $("ul li:first");
```

Are you trying get a reference to the `li` with `class="active"`?

```
var li = $("ul li.active");
```

Once you have the reference you need, you can set attributes or innerHTML:

```
$(li).attr("class", "active");
$(li).addClass("active");
$(li).text("abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ul id="special">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul> 


$(document).ready(function()
{
 $("#special li:eq(0)").addClass("active");
})
```

Check this in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UsvRs/

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
    <li>list item 3</li>
    <li>list item 4</li>
    <li>list item 5</li>
  </ul>
```

if above is your ul li structure you can use below script.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('li').eq(0).addClass("active");
});
```